# Django - get_or_create() with auto_now=True

Tags: python, django

I’m using Django and I'm having a problem with a Python script that uses Django models
The script that I'm using takes data from an api and loads it into my database.

my model:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    tmdb_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    release = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    poster = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    runtime = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    edit = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    backdrop = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    popularity = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

the script:

```
movies = tmdb.Movies().upcoming()
results = movies['results']
ids = []
for movie in results:
    data, created = Movie.objects.get_or_create(title=movie['title'],
                                                tmdb_id=movie['id'],
                                                release=movie['release_date'],
                                                description=movie['overview'],
                                                backdrop=movie['backdrop_path'],
                                                poster=movie['poster_path'],
                                                popularity=movie['popularity'])
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever I run the script, the entries are duplicated because the edit field is change, but the purpose I put the edit field is to know when exactly a movie got edited, ie: some other field got changed.

How can I avoid the duplicates, but also keep the edit field in case some real change happened?

Comment: Did you override the `save()` method in your `Movie` model?

Comment: @CarlosMermingas no I haven't and I'm not quite sure how to do that, I'm fairly new to django

Comment: I see. I was wondering if there was another interaction. I created a small project to replicate this error and I couldn't reproduce it. Could you please double check that this is ***exactly*** the code that you're running? The `backdrop` and `popularity` fields in `get_or_create` do not exist in the Movie model.

Comment: I just accidentally removed them while writing the post, I edited them back there and yes it's the exact code I'm running

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening :-/ I am sorry. I don't think that the `edit` field is the problem. I suggest verifying that all the fields are actually identical between the duplicate records. For example, that *popularity* number probably changes over time.

Comment: I just double checked and yes it wasn't entirely identical it's fixed now! but how can I prevent it from being duplicated if there is some change and instead update the original object? I tried `update_or_create` but it doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124603/discussion-between-carlos-mermingas-and-mari).

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @e4c5 yes I'm sorry I thought I replied to you, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the purpose I put the edit field is to know when exactly a movie
>   got edited, ie: some other field got changed.

That probably means you are using the wrong function. You should be using [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) istead.

> A convenience method for updating an object with the given kwargs,
>   creating a new one if necessary. The defaults is a dictionary of
>   (field, value) pairs used to update the object.

This is different from get_or_create, which creates an object if it does not exists, or simply fetches it when it does exist. update_or_create is the one that does the actually updating.

However, changing to this method doesn't solve this:

> How can I avoid the duplicates, but also keep the edit field in case
>   some real change happened?

Duplicates are created because you do not have a unique index on any of your fields. Both `get_or_create` and `update_or_create` require that you have a unique field. It seems that the following change is in order:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    tmdb_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

Comment: That worked for me by adding `data, created = Movie.objects.update_or_create(tmdb_id=movie['id'], 
                                                   defaults={'title':movie['title'],...)`

Comment: glad to hear. All the best with your project

Comment: Thank you for your help!